# To check multiple data entry in Row/Column of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have the below matrix. My actual matrix is 1000X1000.

```
B = matrix(c(2, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA), nrow = 3, ncol=2)
```

How do I check if there are more than one data entry in a row or a column in R before I process anything from them?

Ex: In the above matrix, there are two data entries in first column(2 and 3) and hence I will process that column.

Will checking for mean of that column > element in a column work?

Comment: Do `colSums(!is.na(B))` or `rowSums(!is.na(B))` work for you? You could select desired column/columns using `B[, colSums(!is.na(B)) > 1, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @David Thanks! It works!